# Parse SSL Certificate Issue

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, ssl-certificate

I've uploaded my certificate and my key and Parse has accepted both, but over 2 hours later it's still serving the *.parseapp.com certificate and not mine (the instructions say certificate changes take up to 30 minutes to propagate).

Do I need to be patient, or do I have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

For people who might stumble upon this:
https://www.parse.com/questions/intermediate-chain-ssl-certificate

basically you have to paste the intermediate keys of your ssl provider in the specific certificate you get for you domain and upload this
to obtain those intermediate certificate you can use a ssl checker like: https://ssltools.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

or look on the website where you bought the ssl certificate